# Check if Images are loaded before gameloop

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

So far my program is working the way I want it to.  This works fine:

```
// Player object
var player = {
   x: 10,
   y: 10,
   draw: function () {
       ctx.drawImage(playerImg, 0, 0);
   ...
```

1. Should I check if `playerImg` is loaded first, even though it works correctly so far?
2. Also, what is the best way to check.  I was thinking about putting all the images in an array.  Then check with the `onLoad` function.  If they are all loaded then I will start the game loop.  Is this a good idea?

Thanks

Comment: You can attach onload event to dynamically downloading of images, If image is fully loaded then mark a boolean value to true, and start you game loop when that boolean is true

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### How image loading works

You need to check if the image is loaded as image loading is asynchronous. You may experience that your code works sometimes without. This is mainly because your image exists in the cache and the browser is able to load it fast enough before the `drawImage` is called, or the image exists on local disk.

However, new users will need to download the data first and you don't want first-time users to experience errors such as images not showing because they are not finished loading.

As it works asynchronous your code will continue to execute *while* the image loading takes place in the background. This may cause your code to execute before the image has finished loading. So handling image loading is important

### Handling multiple images

You can load all your images first (or those you need to start with) and you can define them using array:

```
var imageURLs = [url1, url2, url3, ...],
    images = [],
    count = imageURLs.length;
```

Then iterate and create the image elements:

```
for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {

    /// create a new image element
    var img = new Image();

    /// element is valid so we can push that to stack
    images.push(img);

    /// set handler and url
    img.onload = onloadHandler;
    img.src = imageURLs[i];

    /// if image is cached IE (surprise!) may not trigger onload
    if (img.complete) onloadHandler().bind(img);
}
```

and in the callback function do the inventory count:

```
function onloadHandler() {
    /// optionally: "this" contains current image just loaded
    count--;
    if (count === 0) callbackDone();
}
```

Your callback is the code you want to execute next. Your images will be in the array `images` in the same order as the `imageURLs`.

For production you should also incorporate an `onerror` handler in case something goes wrong.

Comment: If I remember right some IE versions do not trigger the onload event when loaded from cache. After setting the src it might make sense to check if img.complete is true. If yes, you can call the onloadHandler manually, otherwise just bind it to the event.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer.  What if I were to add the images using HTML (but make them invisible).  Then can I just create a function to check if the whole page is loaded?  for example, window.onLoad or document.onLoad.  At that point, I would get the images by their html id and make them visible and in the position I want?

Comment: @Tony that is possible too. Just be aware of that all browsers doesn't behave identical when images are hidden from the start. IIRC older Opera browser won't load the image until it becomes visible which mean you will run into the same problem as you started with.