# Drawing Tile Maps in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am attempting to draw a tile map using 64x64 tileable images onto the HTML5 Canvas. They are named 1.png, 2.png, and 3.png. They are just 64x64 images that I intend to use to tile on a canvas background. 1.png is a pure green image, 2.png is pure grey image, 3.png is a pure brown image.

Here is my HTML:

```
<canvas id='gameCanvas'></canvas>
<script src='Index.js'></script>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas'),
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 512;
canvas.height = 512;
var map = ['2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2',
        '2','1','1','1','1','3','1','1','1','2',
        '2','1','1','1','1','3','1','1','1','2',
        '2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2'],
x = 0,
y = 0,
image = new Image();

for (var j = 0; j < map.length; j++){
    image.onload = function(){
        if(x == 512){
            x = 0;
         y += 64;
    }
    x += 64;
    ctx.drawImage(image, x, y);
}
image.src = 'Images/' + map[j] + '.png';
}
```

For Some reason, it seems to be drawing all the images in one place. I think it has something to do with the `image.onload = functtion(){}`. Can anyone help me make this code draw each image 64 pixels (The width and Height of the images) apart.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to start your loop inside the onload handler. Having onload inside the loop will only trigger once (when the image has loaded, not because of the loop).

```
image.onload = function(){
    for (var j = 0; j < map.length; j++){
        /// todo: actually use map index to determine source rectangle
        /// in spritesheet
        if(x == 512){
            x = 0;
            y += 64;
        }
        x += 64;
        ctx.drawImage(this, x, y);  /// todo: need to specify sprite rectangle
    }
}
```

You will probably also need to specify the source rectangle for your `drawImage()` method but as you don't show the image we can't tell (your loop also ignores the map tile index).

**Update**

Ok, based on comments, here is an example loading images using the YAIL loader (as suggested) integrated into the original code (assuming the script is already included):

### [Demo (with random tiles)](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/vKSKL/)

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = 512;
canvas.height = 512;

var map = [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,  /// use numbers instead of strings here
           2,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,2,
           2,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,2,
           2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
    x = 0,
    y = 0,

    /// loader code
    loader = (new YAIL({
        done: drawTiles,                    /// called when images are loaded
        urls: ['1.png', '2.png', '3.png']   /// order will be preserved
    })).load();                             /// start loading

function drawTiles(e) {

    /// loop and get map index
    for (var j = 0, tile; tile = map[j]; j++){
        if(x == 512){
            x = 0;
            y += 64;
        }
        ctx.drawImage(e.images[tile - 1], x, y);
        x += 64;
    }
}
```

An error handler should be added as well for final code.

Comment: This almost works. I also forgot to mention, my images are named 1.png, 2.png, and 3.png. This only draws the 2.png for some odd reason

Comment: @user3255156 A simpler image loader which may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974517/javascript-check-if-images-are-loaded-before-gameloop/18974956#18974956

Comment: I have downloaded it, unzipped it, and stuck it in there. Can you show me how to use it with my code?

Comment: @user3255156 it's a bit difficult as you are not showing any of the other images you're loading in the question or how you intend to use them, what they contain etc. I would suggest that the question is updated with these details first so we can pinpoint the correct solution right away.

Comment: I posted descriptions of what they are, would not let me post image because my account is new. Hope that helps..

Comment: @user3255156 ouch, I left the closing bracket in the wrong place. See update + demo

Comment: I am getting this error:
ReferenceError: YAIL is not defined

Comment: @UmairHamid YAIL is no more

Comment: God bless YAIL :D