# Drawing two images in Canvas at the same time

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I try to program an online version of Kara (the little ladybug you can program to find the leafs laying in the grid). For that, I programmed some functions to draw the needed objects into the grid. Those functions are:

```
Kara.prototype.draw_object = function (x, y, asset) {
    pos = this.calc_pos(x,y);
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        c.drawImage(img, pos.x, pos.y, 40, 40);
    }
    img.src = asset;
}

Kara.prototype.draw_tree = function(x,y) {
    this.draw_object(x,y,this.assets.asset_tree);
}

Kara.prototype.draw_leaf = function(x,y) {
    this.draw_object(x,y,this.assets.asset_leaf);
}

Kara.prototype.draw_mush = function(x,y) {
    this.draw_object(x,y,this.assets.asset_mush);
}
```

The asset object is defined in the `init` functions and point to png files like `img/tree.png`. `calc_pos` calculates the absolute x and y position depending on the position in the grid.

There is a lot work to do. Because I would like to draw some sample content every time the browser reloads, I wrote a `sample` function:

```
Kara.prototype.sample = function() {
    kara = this;
    kara.draw_kara(1,1);  // Not listed above. Draws the little laddybug
    setTimeout(function() {
        kara.draw_tree(2,1);
    }, 4);
    setTimeout(function() {
        kara.draw_mush(3,1);
    }, 8);
    setTimeout(function() {
        kara.draw_leaf(4,1);
    }, 12);
}
```

Without the timeout everything is drawn to `[4][1]`. Because it worked when I typed every single command in the Developer console I tried to find the root of the bug by placing some waiting time between the draw commands.

If there are 0.5 seconds between the commands everything works perfect. With 4 miliseconds it could work properly or some objects are placed above each other.

Does anybody know an issue where this occured or can give me a hint for the origion of this bug?

Comment: preload the images. you are loading the images for each time which is an async operation which are bound to fail if you don't handle onload handlers properly. With small timeout values as this the image loading is properly not done before you try to load next image.

Comment: An example how you can load multiple images properly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974517/javascript-check-if-images-are-loaded-before-gameloop/18974956#18974956

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So you suggest that I load all images in my init function and store the object that is passed to the callback function in a variable that is accessible from all over my "class"? Seems reasonable. I will give it a try right away.

Comment: Ok, everything worked as expected. The little laddybug is now more or less ready. I you would like to create an anwser I will mark it as solution and therefore the thread as solved