# Only one image being drawn to canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have multiple images I'm trying to draw to the canvas but only one is being done so at a time.  Can anyone explain to me why?

**JSON**

```
"images": [
        {
            "name": "carat_white",
            "src": "images/CaretR-01.png",
            "x": 0,
            "y": 0,
            "dest_x": 548,
            "dest_y": 148,
            "width": 40,
            "height": 40
        },

        {
            "name": "carat_black",
            "src": "images/Caret-01.png",
            "x": 0,
            "y": 0,
            "dest_x": 700,
            "dest_y": 100,
            "width": 40,
            "height": 40
        }
    ]
```

**JS**

```
    var images = result[0].images;
    var imageObj = new Image();
    function drawImages(src, x, y, width, height, dest_x, dest_y, dest_width, dest_height){
        dest_width = (width / 2);
        dest_height = (height / 2);

         imageObj.onload = function(){
            ctx.drawImage(imageObj, x, y, width, height, dest_x, dest_y, dest_width, dest_height);
         }
         imageObj.src = src;
     }

drawImages(images[0].src, images[0].x, images[0].y, images[0].width, images[0].height, images[0].dest_x, images[0].dest_y, images[0].width, images[0].height);

drawImages(images[1].src, images[1].x, images[1].y, images[1].width, images[1].height, images[1].dest_x, images[1].dest_y, images[1].width, images[1].height);
```

If I comment out one of the `drawImages()` functions, the other shows, but if I leave them both 'active' only the latter one shows.  So basically, a new image is drawn, but the older one is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a global declared `imageObj` which means it will be overridden every time you call `drawImages`.

Put it inside the function instead, and use `this` inside the `onload` handler:

```
function drawImages(src, x, y, width, height, dest_x, dest_y, dest_width, dest_height){

    var imageObj = new Image();

    dest_width = (width / 2);
    dest_height = (height / 2);

     imageObj.onload = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(this, x, y, width, height, dest_x, dest_y, dest_width, dest_height);
     }
     imageObj.src = src;
 }
```

If you need to store a reference, push it to a global array:

```
var loadedImages = [];

function drawImages(src, x, y, width, height, dest_x, dest_y, dest_width, dest_height){

    var imageObj = new Image();
    loadedImages.push(imageObj);
    ...
```

Note: if you're using this to draw images on top of each other you need to have in mind that images does not necessarily finish loading the same order as they started (due to different sizes etc.).

Check out one for example **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974517/javascript-check-if-images-are-loaded-before-gameloop/18974956#18974956)** to see how you can load images in order, and when done draw them in order as well.