# html5 canvas, image as background for arch or circle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, background, geometry

Hello Stackoverflow people, my first post here.

I have a circle on canvas, and circle divided into sky and ground portion, and it is (analog) clock looking, so imagine as hands of the clock were extended to the edge of the circle, making two 'pie slices'. And hands are moving. I would like to have different (background) images for those two portions. Now I have gradiant fill, but I would like to change gradiant with appropriate images. The images  must fill their whole portion of 'pie slice'.
My code so far:

```
  // ground portion of circle
  var lingrad=ctx.createLinearGradient(center.x, center.y,center.x,main_radius*2);
  lingrad.addColorStop(0,'green');
  lingrad.addColorStop(1,'brown');
  ctx.fillStyle=lingrad;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(center.x, center.y);
  ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
  ctx.arc(center.x, center.y, radius,  d2r(z1 + 90), d2r(v1 + 90), false);
  ctx.moveTo(center.x, center.y);
  ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  // sky portion of circle
  var lingrad1=ctx.createLinearGradient(center.x,0,center.x,center.y);
  lingrad1.addColorStop(0,'yellow');
  lingrad1.addColorStop(0.5,'yellow');
  lingrad1.addColorStop(1,'cyan');
  ctx.fillStyle=lingrad1;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(center.x, center.y);
  ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
  ctx.arc(center.x, center.y, radius,  d2r(z1 + 90), d2r(v1 + 90), true);
  ctx.moveTo(center.x, center.y);
  ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
```

thank you and sorry for my english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use for example `clip()` to do this by first defining the clip path using `arc()`, call `clip()`, then draw in the two images in each half.

A simple example:

```js
var img1 = new Image, img2 = new Image, count = 0, ctx = c.getContext("2d");
img1.onload = img2.onload = go;
img1.src = "//i.stack.imgur.com/EU6KB.jpg";
img2.src = "//i.stack.imgur.com/UmEA9.jpg";

function go() {
  if (++count < 2) return;  // just to make sure both images has loaded
  
  // save state as restoring is the only way to remove a clip-mask
  ctx.save();
  
  // define clip-mask using path operations
  ctx.arc(75, 75, 75, 0, 6.28);
  ctx.clip();
  
  // draw in top image
  ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);

  // draw in bottom image
  ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 75);
  
  // remove clip mask
  ctx.restore();
}
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

You can of course use the position, size as well as clipping arguments of [`drawImage()`](https://devdocs.io/dom/canvasrenderingcontext2d/drawimage) to taste.

Comment: If I read the question right, I think OP wants something more flexible than just split in the middle, something like https://jsfiddle.net/2j324gsn, which also exerpts that `clip` is really not good for non straight shapes (white artifacts) and that gCO might be preferable, at the cost of a second canvas https://jsfiddle.net/2j324gsn/1

Comment: K3N, your code is spot on, thank you so much. I implemented your code and works nicely... but another problem arose, I have several icons that should be drawn on top of divided circle from loop statement, which are now not. As I put alert() before draw icon, funny thing happens, it draws icons on top as it should, but without alert() it does not. I tried with loading image and without, I tried to put variables in array, to be drawn after loop, still no go... Kaiido, well, that looks interesting, I will certainly fiddle a bit with it, since I am still canvas noob. Thanks for time and input.

Comment: @GoranMitić you're probably dealing with async loading problem. Pleasee check out for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18974956/1693593) for how to preload many images.